# Typescript Error : Declaring a parameter as a union of interfaces. Instead of picking one of the choices, it picks all of them

Tags: typescript, interface, function-parameter

This is the code I want to write

```
interface InputField{
    formHeading:string,
    isText:boolean,
    fields:any[]
}

interface InfoField{
    formHeading:string,
    isText:boolean,
    textData:string[]
}

let testInfoField: InputField|InfoField;

testInfoField = {
    formHeading : "hello",
    isText : true,
    textData : ['hi', 'hello']
};

console.log(testInfoField.textData)
// Works fine here

let testInputField: InputField|InfoField;
testInputField = {
    formHeading : "Hi",
    isText : false,
    fields: [1,2,3,4]
}

console.log(testInputField.fields);
// Works fine here



const func = (Field:InfoField|InputField) =>{
    if(Field.isText){
        console.log("TextField text", Field.textData);
        // Error in using Field.textData now

    }
    else{
        console.log("Input Field", Field.fields);
        // Error in using Field.inputField now
    }
}
```

So, according to what I know in Typescript using union means you can use any of the interfaces. So, why it's not working in the function **func**?
The error I got was :

> Property 'textData' does not exist on type 'InputField | InfoField'.
> Property 'textData' does not exist on type 'InputField'.
> Property 'inputField' does not exist on type 'InputField | InfoField'.
> Property 'inputField' does not exist on type 'InputField'.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this? If I am using textData, then that means I want to use the InfoField interface, not InputField. It shouldn't matter if it doesn't exist on the InputField.

The function parameter value will automatically come as one of the two choices.

Why when used as a parameter, it is demanding a combined object? It's like it creates a big object consisting of all values of InfoField and InputField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both of your types have `isText: boolean`, so either of them could have `true` or `false` for that, so `if (Field.isText)` doesn't narrow the union type.

You need to declare the type of `isText` as a *literal* `true` or `false` in order to create a [*discriminated union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions):

```typescript
interface InputField{
    formHeading:string,
    isText:false, // ***
    fields:any[]
}

interface InfoField{
    formHeading:string,
    isText:true,  // ***
    textData:string[]
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#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-tk7oV6teWzWIA)

---

Side note: The playground link shows that using `Field.textData` works with the change. Using `Field.inputField` still doesn't work, because *neither* of the union types has a property called `inputField`. You probably meant `fields`.